# Wordpress Loop repeating twice

Tags: wordpress, loops

Hello I have a while loop in WordPress and I am adding an active class on the first instance of the loop and this works fine but the same instance then again repeats afterwards without the active class.

here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                        <?php
          query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'deal','dealtype' => 'deals' ) );
          while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>

                                <?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) {  ?>

                                 <div class="item active">
                           <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
                                <?php 

                $thumb_id = get_field('featured_image'); 
                $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
                $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

?>  
                                 <img src="<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                 <div class="featuredContent">
                                    <div class="contentTitle">
                                       <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="contentDetails">
                                       <p><?php echo get_field('sub_title'); ?>
                                       </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if(get_field('max_amount')) { ?>
                                    <div class="contentDetails">
                                       <p>Up to 
                                       <?php the_field('max_amount'); ?>


                                       Shares</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <!--
                                    <div class="contentLink">
                                       <p><a href="#">invest now</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="contentLink">
                                       <p><a href="#">follow offering</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    -->
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>

                                <?php }  ?>


                        <div class="item">
                           <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
                                <?php 

                $thumb_id = get_field('featured_image'); 
                $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
                $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

?>  
                                 <img src="<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                 <div class="featuredContent">
                                    <div class="contentTitle">
                                       <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="contentDetails">
                                       <p><?php echo get_field('sub_title'); ?>
                                       </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if(get_field('max_amount')) { ?>
                                    <div class="contentDetails">
                                       <p>Up to 
                                       <?php the_field('max_amount'); ?>


                                       Shares</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <!--
                                    <div class="contentLink">
                                       <p><a href="#">invest now</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="contentLink">
                                       <p><a href="#">follow offering</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    -->
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>






                      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>  






                     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe you need to add an `else` statement after your `<?php if ($wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { ?>` statement ends. Should look something like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                    <?php
      query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'deal','dealtype' => 'deals' ) );
      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>

                            <?php if ( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { ?>

                             <div class="item active">
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <?php 

            $thumb_id = get_field('featured_image'); 
            $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
            $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

?>  
                             <img src="<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                             <div class="featuredContent">
                                <div class="contentTitle">
                                   <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="contentDetails">
                                   <p><?php echo get_field('sub_title'); ?>
                                   </p>
                                </div>
                                <?php if(get_field('max_amount')) { ?>
                                <div class="contentDetails">
                                   <p>Up to 
                                   <?php the_field('max_amount'); ?>


                                   Shares</p>
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <!--
                                <div class="contentLink">
                                   <p><a href="#">invest now</a></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="contentLink">
                                   <p><a href="#">follow offering</a></p>
                                </div>
                                -->
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                            <?php } else {  ?>


                    <div class="item">
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <?php 

            $thumb_id = get_field('featured_image'); 
            $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
            $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

?>  
                             <img src="<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                             <div class="featuredContent">
                                <div class="contentTitle">
                                   <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="contentDetails">
                                   <p><?php echo get_field('sub_title'); ?>
                                   </p>
                                </div>
                                <?php if(get_field('max_amount')) { ?>
                                <div class="contentDetails">
                                   <p>Up to 
                                   <?php the_field('max_amount'); ?>


                                   Shares</p>
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <!--
                                <div class="contentLink">
                                   <p><a href="#">invest now</a></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="contentLink">
                                   <p><a href="#">follow offering</a></p>
                                </div>
                                -->
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                        <?php } ?>




                  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>  






                 </div>
```